# Is it possible to set a given range with FileWebRequest, similarly to HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I'm currently attempting to download a file through `WebRequest.Create(url)`, getting a `FileWebRequest`.

I was wondering if it would be possible to pass in a given download range so I could potentially download different file chunks in parallel. I've noticed that in contrast with `HttpWebRequest`, there's no `AddRange()` method but maybe through a correct conjugation of other parameters such behavior could be achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can since FileWebRequest refer to request using the file:// uri scheme. This scheme does not involve a specific protocol (as far as I know) like http:// uri scheme involving HTTP protocol which includes headers to partially download content.

If you are trying to open a remote file, you may consider the use of a specific protocol like FTP which may allow you to do want you want instead of file uris.